# Wildfly Artemis ActiveMQ lookup fail

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, javabeans, activemq-artemis

My lookup for a que fail. The que is registered in the wildfly and configured with ironjacamar.xml

**wildfly** output on start:

```
Bound JCA AdminObject [java:jboss/activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue]
```

**ironjacamar** config:

```
       <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
            jndi-name="java:jboss/activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue">
            <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue
            </config-property>
        </admin-object>
```

ra.xml:

```
   <adminobject>
        <adminobject-interface>javax.jms.Topic</adminobject-interface>
        <adminobject-class>org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic</adminobject-class>
        <config-property>
            <config-property-name>PhysicalName</config-property-name>
            <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
        </config-property>
    </adminobject>
```

My exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.InvalidDestinationRuntimeException: Foreign destination:queue://activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSProducer.send(ActiveMQJMSProducer.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSProducer.send(ActiveMQJMSProducer.java:121)
```

my Bean include:

```
@Inject
private JMSContext context;    
@Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue")
private Queue queue;
```

i also tried:

```
@Inject
private JMSContext context;    
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue")
private Queue queue;
```

Did anyone has an idea what i did wrong?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're attempting to use the admin object from the ActiveMQ 5.x JCA resource adapter to configure a JMS queue, but then you're using the ActiveMQ Artemis client to work with that queue.  ActiveMQ 5.x and ActiveMQ Artemis are completely different client/server implementations.  You can't mix them like that.

Comment: so basicly i used the wrong adapter resource?
 first i used the old activemq 5.x, but i had the same error, so thatswhy i tried the artemis. but i will try the artemis adapter as next. thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter as much which resource adapter you actually use. You just need to match the resource adapter and the client.

Comment: I tried both now. I updated to Artemis ActiveMQ and got the same error :-/ I can listen to the queue, but cannot send any information to the queue.

Comment: It will be basically impossible to diagnose the issue in the comments here. Ask a new question with the details of your new configuration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828796/wildfly-15-external-artemis-activemq-destination-not-found here is my new question. Thanks for the help!