# Wildfly 15 external Artemis ActiveMQ destination not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have a wildfly 15 with an external ActiveMQ and use a resource adapter. But i cannot get a connection to a queue to write on.

But I can listen at the queue.

here is my configuration:

ironjacamar.xml:

```
<admin-objects>
    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
            jndi-name="java:jboss/activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue1234">
        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue
        </config-property>
    </admin-object>
</admin-objects>
```

ra.xml:

```
<adminobject>
    <adminobject-interface>javax.jms.Queue</adminobject-interface>
    <adminobject-class>org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue</adminobject-class>
    <config-property>
        <config-property-name>PhysicalName</config-property-name>
        <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    </config-property>
</adminobject>
```

Bean.java:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue1234")
private Queue queue;
@Inject
private JMSContext context;
someFunction(){
    context.createProducer().send(queue, "hier ist eine nachricht");
}
```

My listener bean:

```
@ResourceAdapter("activemq.rar")
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue") })
public class RemoteActiveMQConsumer implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                final String text = ((TextMessage) msg).getText();
                System.out.println(text);
            } catch (final JMSException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml for Beans contains:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

this is the same version of jar like in the resource adapter.

Reading from the `HELLOWORLDMDBQueue` is not a problem, but if i try to send, i get the following output:

Error:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Foreign destination:queue://activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.checkDestination(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:349)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:217)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:206)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQRAMessageProducer.java:142)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSProducer.send(ActiveMQJMSProducer.java:98)
```

*Thanks for help*

Comment: My Artemis ActiveMQ Version is `Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.3`

Comment: Addressing has changed between Artemis 1.5 and 2.6. Wildfly is still using the old prefix by default. Either rename your 'remote' queues or use setEnable1xPrefixes(false) on the resource adapter.

Comment: how can i set this in my resource adapter?because i only working with the ra.xml :-D, and what you mean with rename the remote queues? thanks!

Comment: I tried to rename the queue to `jms.queue.activemq/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue` but had no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [your other question on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498387/wildfly-artemis-activemq-lookup-fail), it appears that you're attempting to use the admin object from the ActiveMQ 5.x JCA resource adapter to configure a JMS queue admin object, but then you're using the ActiveMQ Artemis client to work with that queue. ActiveMQ 5.x and ActiveMQ Artemis are completely different client/server implementations. You can't mix them like that.

You do not need to configure anything related to the ActiveMQ 5.x JCA resource adapter. Simply define your queue in Wildfly's `messaging` subsystem and create connection factories which point to the remote broker.

Comment: you can use external connection factories and queues (without the internal broker) in WF15

Comment: It would be awesome to get an explanation of that in a full answer.

Comment: ok, but I am using an activemq Artemis as an external broker, I have to look again at the resource adapter. I am confused, because I can read from queues :-D

Comment: I imagine you can read from the queues because the MDB is using the ActiveMQ 5.x JCA RA which is communicating over the OpenWire protocol which ActiveMQ Artemis supports. However, you still can't mix *objects* from one client implementation with the other.